# Backup Azure Virtual Machine local folders to blob storage?

Tags: azure, backup, virtual-machine, azure-blob-storage

I've just setup an extra small VM instance in Windows Azure to run a help console for our company. The help files can be updated and published through a simple .NET interface. Obviously the flat html files are getting deployed to the local drive on the VM and exposed publicly through IIS. I'm just wondering how stable this is? If the VM suffers a hardware failure, presumably there's no automatic failover and any edits we've made to the help system will be lost?

Can anyone recommend a way I can shuttle the source files out of the VM into blob storage? I could write a an application to do this, I'm just wondering if there is an out-of-the-box solution out there?

***Additional information:***

- The VM instance is running Server 2008 R2 SP1 (As a Virtual Machine not a web-role)
- A backup needs to be created once every 24 hours
- Aged backups (3+ days old) need to be automatically cleared from the blob container
- The help system we use is called HelpConsole 2012
- New pages are added at a rate of myabe 2-3 per week

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer depends on how whether you are running this in a Windows Azure Virtual Machine or on a Windows Azure Web role.

If you are running this on a Windows Azure Virtual Machine, then the VHD is stored in BLOB storage and, if the site is running of the C: drive and not on a data Disk, then the system has some Host caching turned on for both reads and writes.  In this scenario it is possible (depending on the methods you use to write your files out) that the data is not pushed back to the VHD in BLOB storage before a failure occurs.  You can either ensure that your writing methods do a write through operation, or turn off the write caching.  Better yet, attach a data disk for your web site files.  By default data disks have both read and write caching off (you could turn on read caching).  Since the VHD's are persisted you don't have to worry about the concern of the edits getting lost.  You can script out taking a snapshot of the files and move them to BLOB storage separately, or even push them somewhere else.  Another thing to think about with this option is that you have to care for the VM instances and keep them patched and up to date.

If you are running a Web Role, then yes, if a failure occurs and the VM goes through self healing it will indeed redeploy with the older files.  In this case I'd recommend changing the code in the web role that when it writes the updates to the local file it also puts a copy of the local file into BLOB Storage.  In addition, in the web role OnStart you could reach out to BLOB storage and pull down all the new content locally.  BE VERY CAREFUL with this approach though because it only really works well for ONE instance, not multiple.  If you plan on running multiple instances of the server (and you will have to if you want the SLA for uptime) then your code will need to be a little more robust and do writes out to BLOB storage and then alert all instances of the role that there is a new file to pull down locally.

Another option for web roles is to also write a handler for the content so that requests come in and are mapped to a file BLOB Storage directly.  Then updates can occur to direct edits to the file in BLOB storage.  This offloads the serving of the flat files from your compute nodes to BLOB storage and you could even implement some caching and stream the content back through the handler rather than having them hit BLOB storage directly if you wanted to.

Now, another option, is to use Windows Azure Web Sites for this.  The underlying storage of the web site files in Windows Azure Web Sites is a shared location and thus updating the files in it will immediately be reflected for all instances.  Also, the content for the site is stored in BLOB storage and can be updated via FTP, source control, or directly from code.  Lots of options here.  You may end up moving to reserved instances to help keep away from some of the quotas that Web Sites have.  Web Sites may not be an option for you currently depending on other requirements (as in how much control do you need over the environment since you don't get a lot of control for Web Sites).

Comment: Mike, thanks for your very comprehensive response! We are running off a Virtual Machine not a web-role. I can now view the .vhd image in the blob container from Visual Studio. I have deployed all the source files to the D: drive (Temporary Storage), which I think will need moving to C: in order to be mapped to the .vhd? I opted for a VM over a website or web-role as the help system is deployed from an exe installer which relies on a bunch of dependencies that would require a startup script to achieve in a web-role. Using RDP to get the site working was a quiker solution for me.

Comment: I should also add that the help system on this VM only gets modified once per week at the most.

Comment: Ah, yes, definitely move the files off the D: drive.  That drive is temporary.  I'd recommend creating a data disk if you don't want the files on C: and putting the web site there.  But, once the data is on the C: or a data disk (not the default D:) then the data is persisted even if the machine goes down (again, be aware of what drive caching settings are set up).  Given your indication of additional dependencies it makes sense of using a VM over a web role to get you going, but I'd suggest looking at how to get to a web role in the future to reduce your maintenance requirements for patching.

Comment: If it was me I would create a data disk to host the files on and not put it on C:.  More flexibility that way and your files are not on the same drive as your OS.

Comment: Excellent! Just so I understand the .vhd file is an image of the C: drive on the VM? How often does this .vhd file get refreshed? I copied a chunk of data into the C: drive and refreshed the blob browser and the .vhd didn't change in size? If I setup a data drive will that create a separate blob container specific to that drive? Sorry for all the questions...this is all new to me!

Comment: Yes, the VHD for C: is stored as a file in BLOB storage.  Note that the BLOB file may or may not grow in size as you add stuff depending on if the BLOB browser is looking at the "reserved" amount of space or the actual used amount of space.  Check these out: http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/manage/windows/how-to-guides/attach-a-disk/ and http://michaelwasham.com/2012/06/08/understanding-windows-azure-virtual-machines/

Comment: Thank you so much! The guides are a big help!